# Starring or Pinning a message that got cleared by a room owner gives off a wrong error message

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, room-owner

Imagine the following situation:

1. Message gets posted in room
2. User A (room owner) pins the message (or for that matter, user a which is not a room owner, stars it).
3. User B (another room owner) clears pins/stars from that message.
4. Both users A and a cannot pin/star the message again, however, they get the following error message:

   > You have already voted, but the voting has been cleared by a moderator

This is slightly confusing (because generally there are no mods in the room) and leads to wondering what the hell happened.

Can this be changed to something like

> You have already voted, but the voting has been cleared by a moderator or a room owner.

(or even better if there can be a distinction between the two)

Not a major bug, but a little annoyance that's bugging me for quite a while.